# PHP Create new class instance - singleton and factory pattern

Tags: php, class, instance

I have the following PHP Class:

```
class Init {

private static $instance = NULL;

public function __construct(){
}

public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments){

    if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
        $class = '\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\Drivers\\' . $name;

        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);
        self::$instance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($arguments);

        return self::$instance;
    } else {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

}

Is there any other way to call the instantiated class, with the arguments array in that order, **without using Reflection** ?
I've tried call_user_func_array() but it seems it doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Is there a reason `ReflectionClass` is not ok while `call_user_func_array` is ok?

Comment: My class will be dependent to the ReflectionClass and i don't really know if that's ok.

Comment: Do you mean you might  use it in PHP that doesn't support it? Otherwise it's exactly the same result as creating the instance normally

Comment: _Do you mean you might use it in PHP that doesn't support it?_ 

Yes. Is that possible ?

Comment: No, it was introduced in [php 5.1.3](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.3). Namespaces were introduced much later, in [5.3 I believe](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php), so if you are using them in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
public class Example{
    private static $instance;
    public static function singleton($arguments)
        {
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
                echo 'Creating new instance.';
                $className = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $className($arguments);
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using echo in a class. Instead use comments and exceptions where necessarily ;-)

Comment: If i use this, the instantiated class cunstruct will receive an only one argument. In the initiated class constructor i want to have something like this:
`__construct($name, $city, $etc){
}`